# Setting up OGRE 3D and cmake for Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, cmake

Anyone know how to install OGRE 3D for Ubuntu 14.10 and how to make it work with `cmake`?
I'm trying to do a project and I'm a newbie with Ubuntu and `cmake` and everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libogre-1.9-dev cmake
```

should get you everything you need to develop with Ogre and also install CMake.

You might want to follow a guide or tutorial to get a grasp of Ogre first.

And especially make sure you're comfortable with the code before you mess with a build system like CMake - unless your IDE forces it on you, in which case it should do most of the work for you as well. If it forces CMake but doesn't do most of the work, for you, throw it away and use Gedit for editing and GCC directly for compiling.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot for the answer, yes my IDE force me to use cmake but is a awesome IDE. I'll try a little more and if continue the problem i'll throw it and use openGL. PD: in my university the teacher give us the options openGL or ogre3D.